# How can i do multiple file upload using Drupal 7 Form API?

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7, form-api

I'd like to upload multiple files using Form API.

`'#type' => 'file'` provides upload only one file.

```
$form['picture_upload'] = array( 
  '#type' => 'file', 
  '#title' => t(''), 
  '#size' => 50, 
  '#description' => t(''),
  '#weight' => 5,               
);
```

How can i provide multiple upload?

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this issue for days without luck... Unfortunately all the good batch uploaders from D6 were either using depreciated methods or simply not updated for D7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to a issue I had: [Drupal 7 retain file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739345/drupal-7-retain-file-upload)

You can use `managed_file` element type instead of `file`

here's the drupal documentation: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file

Comment: Accepted answer? Why? This is not a solution for multiple file upload.

Comment: For Drupal 7, plupload module (mentioned in another answer on this page) seems to be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from putting the form element in a *for* loop, I would suggest (for now) using the plupload form element.

http://drupal.org/project/plupload

Then:

```
$form['picture_upload'] = array( 
  '#type' => 'plupload', 
  '#title' => t(''), 
  '#size' => 50, 
  '#description' => t(''),
  '#weight' => 5,               
);
```